# Unreported exception Exception

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement

Receiving an `unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown` in my switch statement. I'm not sure why I'm receiving it on just this case and none of the others. I'm receiving the error on case 4 and specifically on null.

Here is the code:

```
private static void runProgram(int selection) throws IOException {
    switch(selection) {
        case 1: PrimeNumbers.main(null);
        break;

        case 2: ParsePhrase.main(null);
        break;

        case 3: Converter.main(null);
        break;

        case 4: DepartmentStore.main(null);
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Does some of the `Thing.main(null)` method throws an Exception ?

Comment: Can you share the declarations, especially the `throws` clauses of the `main` methods you're calling?

Comment: I just managed to get it working. Though I'm extremely confused on how. So I went into my DepartmentStore project and removed the "throws IOException" from the main method and added it back in. Seems to be working now.

Comment: checked exceptions have to be caught or listed in the method signature